# x86_64 assembly execve *char[] syscall

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, execve

I am trying to get into a bit of Linux 64bit x86 assembly without using the standard libs, however I am having some issues dealing with arguments presented to my program (argv). I would think (based on documentation) that `rsp` marks the beginning of the argc qword, whilst `[rsp + 8]` would be argv. Unfortunately this is not the case, and the following (abridged) program causes `EFAULT (Bad address)`.

```
sys_execve equ 59
sys_exit equ 60

section .data
    child db "/bin/sh", 0

global _start

section .text
    _start:
        mov rdi, child      ; #1 filename
        mov rsi, [rsp + 8]      ; #2 argv
        mov rdx, 0      ; #3 envp = 0

        mov rax, sys_execve ; execve
        syscall
        mov rax, rdi        ; #1 Return value
        mov rax, sys_exit   ; exit
        syscall
```

Help with regards to the amd64 calling convention and passing `*char[]` into the kernel would be appreciated.

Comment: If I change the code in question to `xor rsi, [esp + 4]`, strace shows a useful argv being based to exec, yay! However the program subsequently segfaults. Passing a null pointer (0) allows sh to run fine.

Comment: The above should read `mov rsi, [esp+4]`

Comment: Nevermind I was reading strace completely wrong and looking at me execve'ing the test. The above code actually causes a segfault straight away

Comment: Related: [How to pass argv arguments to execv in asm on 64-bit (linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56047512) shows passing static strings in `.rodata` as `argv[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At `rsp+8` you'll find the address of a string with the program path. The pointer to the first argument is at `[rsp+16]`. But for `execve` you need a pointer to an array of pointer to strings which begins with a pointer to a program path (you can (ab)use `[rsp+8]`).

So change

```
mov rsi, [rsp + 8]
```

to

```
lea rsi, [rsp + 8]
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Out of interest would there be an easy way to pass in envp as well, I assume `rsi + argc*8` would be sufficient.

Comment: @md_5: There is a null-pointer between the arguments and the environment. This works: `mov rdx, [rsp] --- lea rdx, [rsp+8 + rdx*8 + 8]`.

Comment: Ah right, forgot about the second null pointer. Thanks for all your help!