# Got segmentation fault after run the compiled asm file

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

```
segment .text
    global _start

_start:
    jmp call_shellcode

shellcode:

    pop rbx
    xor rax, rax

    mov [rbx+7], al
    mov [rbx+8], rbx
    mov [rbx+16], rax

    mov al, 59
    lea rdi, [rbx+7]
    lea rsi, [rbx+8]
    lea rdx, [rbx+16]

    syscall
call_shellcode:
    call shellcode
    shellpath db "/bin/sh0aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb"
```

I tried to run the program which was compiled from this asm file. I checked every step thought nothing was wrong, but I still got segmentation error. Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: thanks! so what should I add at the end?

Comment: yeah.. I am new to asm and shellcode. This code intends to run spawn the shell where the shellpath indicates the directory of shell.

Comment: I removed my old comments because I'm beginning to see what the code is trying to do. It seems to, in a tricky way, trying to obtain the address of `shellpath` by popping it off the stack (left there by the `call`). Where did this come from?

Comment: its one of the exercises I am doing. Do you have any suggestions to modify this code to make it work?

Comment: The problem is that the code is attempting to write a value to the `.text` segment which is not allowed. Here's a [simple example of x86_64 code which spawns a shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135218/x86-64-assembly-execve-char-syscall).

Comment: this would work, but I have to put the final shellcode into a C program. So this is why I use the above format

Comment: If you try to write to the text segment, it will fault. That's why you're seeing the fault.

Comment: I deleted the segment .text header, but it still gives me the same fault...sigh

Comment: It's probably defaulting to the code (text) segment. And you can't define code in the `bss` section, which is the section where you put writable data.